# Options for the function 'Classify'

Tags: options, machine-learning

One of the `Method` options to `Classify` is `NearestNeighbors`. To set up a NearestNeighbors-based classification (`nnclas`) using the training set `tset`, we would use `nnclas = Classify[tset, Method->"NearestNeighbors"];`

I have two questions:-

1. What is the default number of neighbors?
2. Is there any control on the number of neighbors that are used?

`Spelunk`, while interesting, is not particularly illuminating.

I'm using 11.01.

Answer (score 10):

Take the first example from the documentation

```
trainingset = {1 -> "A", 2 -> "A", 3.5 -> "B", 4 -> "B"};
```

and use a nearest neighbor classifier to find out the options

```
Classify[trainingset, Method -> "NearestNeighbors"] // Options
```

[image: options]

In the `Models` section you can find the parameters used by the nearest neighbor algorithm; in the case of `"NeighborNumber"` this seems to work when supplying this as nested `Method`-call

```
Classify[trainingset, Method ->{"NearestNeighbors", "NeighborsNumber" -> 2}] //Options
```

[image: samples]

Comment: Too easy!  Brilliant response, and up-voted accordingly.